# CGI.http_user_agent is empty RAILO

Tags: variables, coldfusion, http-headers, cgi, railo

I am trying to display `CGI.http_user_agent` using RAILO but for some reason it is empty. Has anyone else had this issue? Isn't this supposed to exist all of the time?

I have checked my logs and sometimes it exists and sometimes it does not.

Comment: You should provide more info regarding your setup.  What web server? Apache? IIS? Coyote?  What servlet container?  Tomcat? Resin?

Answer (score 3):

The HTTP user agent is one of the headers["User-Agent"] a browser usually sends. It is neither required nor authoritative.  Some browsers have options to fake to user agent (for example the blackberry browser), and others like cfhttp can be set to whatever the user wants.

If the browser does not send the header it will be blank in RAILO.